# Not able to connect to a Fedora 11 PC via ssh

Tags: ssh, fedora-11

What could be the possible solution to solve this problem in my fedora 11 pc which is not allowing any users to connect to it via ssh? But the reverse is possible, i.e. i am able to connect to other PCs from this problem PC via ssh.

This is the out put i see:

```
[root@myFedoraPC]# ssh sen@10.47.5.100
ssh: connect to host 10.47.5.100 port 22: Connection refused
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: Are you sure you a) installed `openssh-server` and it is running and b) that you aren't running the built-in firewall?

Comment: how to check if openssh-server is running or not?

Comment: i have already disabled firewall..

Comment: @Sen Try `service sshd start` and see what it outputs. Also see this [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/30701/how-to-enable-sshd-on-fedora-11/30707#30707)

Comment: Actually it was a problem with my /var/empty directory.  It had full permissions, which was not allowed.

Comment: @Sen So that fixed it? Post your solution as an answer and you can accept it in two days!

Answer (score 0):

Just went to / path.
Checked the permissions and found that someone has given the /var directory full permissions(0777 mode).

Went into superuser mode and changed the /var permissions to "0755".
And everything was working fine.

Thanks for all your helps.

Sen